# skimage imsave - order of axes in 3-channel TIF file

Tags: python, image, tiff, scikit-image

I have a 3-channel TIF file (a microscopy image with 3 grayscale channels) which is saved as XYC

If I open it using

```
from skimage.io import imread, imsave
import numpy as np

cells = imread("cells_segm.tif")
print(cells.shape)
```

I get `(1024, 1024, 3)`

Now I would like to save it with the channel first, so CXY

I can do

```
cells = np.moveaxis(cells, 2, 0)
print(cells.shape) # This shows (3, 1024, 1024) as expected

imsave("cells_segm2.tif", cells)
cells = imread("cells_segm2.tif")
print(cells.shape) # This shows (1024, 1024, 3)!
```

I am sure I am missing something obvious here, but cannot figure it out...

Comment: Maybe the shape you get from imread is the default for tiff reading, or even writing, which would imply an atuomatic reshape by the I/O functions. Check if there is any difference between the saved image files with and without moveaxis. I would either save in another format (binary numpy.save, pickle...) or change the shape after loading.

Comment: That's because RGB images are returned as MxNx3 by [scikit-image imread](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.imread). Anyway, this is part of a bigger issue. See https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/pull/1498 and the links at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks @cgohlke I was starting to suspect that was the case. Easy to fix in my code, yet very much annoying! I guess you can convert your comment into an answer,it may be useful for someone else!